# Android - prompt users to update app?

Tags: android, json, api, google-play

Does Google provide a JSON API for their Play Store of some sort that would allow me to do something like compare version numbers?  I've looked around and the only solution people are proposing is to scrape the store website and some of those answers are very old.  Are there any libraries available?

I know apple has a way of doing this via url: http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=com.example.app

Comment: You should not prompt users to update your app. The play store already does that for you. Just as basically all devices nowadays already automatically download updates as they become available.

Comment: Just consider all the problems you could cause by doing this. Releases of your app are rolled out over a couple of hours and not all users receive them at the same time. What if the users gets your prompt but the update is not yet available in the play store? It could take hours until the users could actually download the update. Only confusion and the feeling that your app isn't working right would follow.

Comment: Or what if the user doesn't receive the update at all? What if the user has a phone which doesn't support a new feature you introduced in your update? That user will never be eligible to receive the update so do you really want to prompt him? And if you wanted to filter such users out how would you do that? The play store handles all that already for you. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: What if there's a critical update to patch a security flaw and we've applied the fix on the backend but will only allow users to log in if they have the latest version?

Comment: Then you already did everything right. You fixed the issue in the backend and with that made further exploitation of the issue impossible. The update will roll out through the play store and reach your users at its own pace not yours. You can prompt your users as much as you want but that will not make Google roll out the update any faster. Although blocking your users from logging in just because they don't have the newest just released version is kind of extreme. Would you really ever want to do that? Especially when the issue is already fixed in the backend?

Comment: Remember that your userbase will never all be on the newest version. There are android devices in all shapes and sizes with all kinds of different features. As a result your userbase will never all be able to collectively be on the newest version of your app. It's just impossible.